# How do I Get values out of grid class in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm creating a UI instance with a grid object.  I create some items inside for example 5 text boxes.  I pass the grid via a callback element but I have no idea how to call the values with the e.parameter.  Any reason why this isn't working?

```
      function first()
        {
         var appheight = 360;
           var appwidth = 500;
            var defcolumns = 8;
           //Get the spreadsheet we are working on and Create a UI
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(appwidth).setHeight(appheight).setTitle('Step 1:  Set Information');
        var mainGrid = app.createGrid(5, 1).setId("mainGrid"); 
        for(var r=0;r < 5;r++)
        {
         var columnname = app.createTextBox().setText(r.toString());
        mainGrid.setWidget(r, 0, columnname);
         }

      var steptwohandler =   app.createServerClickHandler("steptwo").addCallbackElement(mainGrid);
    var nextbutton = app.createButton().setId("btnnext").setText("Next ->").addClickHandler(steptwohandler);


}

function steptwo()
{
 var app =UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   //See how many rows exist already
    Logger.log(e.parameter.mainGrid);
  for(var r=0;r <=5; r++)
  {
    //should log 1-5 and the mainGrid object;
    Logger.log(r);
    Logger.log(e.parameter.mainGrid[r]);
  }

}
```

I've seen the ability to do something similar in the doctopus script but can't figure out how he is going about solving it.

Comment: To Clarify the number of columns is being generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the name on each of the text boxes too. See the modified code below

```
 function first()
        {
         var appheight = 360;
           var appwidth = 500;
            var defcolumns = 8;
           //Get the spreadsheet we are working on and Create a UI
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(appwidth).setHeight(appheight).setTitle('Step 1:  Set Information');
        var mainGrid = app.createGrid(5, 1).setId("mainGrid"); 
        for(var r=0;r < 5;r++)
        {
         /* Set a name for each text box */
         var columnname = app.createTextBox().setText(r.toString())
            .setName('columnname' + r.toString());
        mainGrid.setWidget(r, 0, columnname);
         }

      var steptwohandler =   app.createServerClickHandler("steptwo").addCallbackElement(mainGrid);
    var nextbutton = app.createButton().setId("btnnext").setText("Next ->").addClickHandler(steptwohandler);


}

/* Receive e as a parameter */
function steptwo(e)
{
 var app =UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   //See how many rows exist already
    Logger.log(e.parameter.mainGrid);
  for(var r=0;r <=5; r++)
  {
    //should log 1-5 and the mainGrid object;
    Logger.log(r);
    //Logger.log(e.parameter.mainGrid[r]);
    Logger.log(e.parameter['columnname' + r.toString()]);
  }

}
```